# Replace function in dataframe removes more than expected

Tags: python, pandas, csv, replace

Suppose I have the following csv file:

```
Column1;Column2
AB; Test
```

Which has a NUL byte character in it:

[image: n1]

I want to read it in with pandas, manipulate it and export it again. I want to remove NUL byte characters, my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\folder\test.csv', sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
df=df.replace('\x00','', regex=True) 
df.to_csv(r'C:\folder\testoutput.csv', sep=";", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

I expect that only the NUL byte character is removed, however, more is removed:

[image: n2]

So it removes the whole "cell", also the "Test". But I don't want this.

Why, where is my mistake? How can I only remove the NUL byte character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not coming from the `replace`, but rather from the fact that the NULL character is handled as a line terminator by [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

What you can do it manually remove the NULL before passing it to `read_csv`:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO(open(r'C:\folder\test.csv').read().replace('\x00', ''))

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2
0      AB    Test
```

Alternatively, if you just want to remove the NULL without pandas:

```
with open(r'C:\folder\test.csv', 'r') as f1, open(r'C:\folder\test_clean.csv', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        f2.write(line.replace('\x00', ''))
```